# std::cout, is binary a faster way to write output?

Tags: c++, binary, ofstream

I am currently writing a simulation in C++ (on OSX). The biggest time effort runs into storing the data, where the output is a table of double pairs t and f(t).

Until now I used the (simplified) code:

```
ofstream ofs;
ofs.open("test");
for(int i = 0; i < 4e7; i++){
    ofs << i;
}

ofs.close();
```

Since everthing is stored in 1's and 0's my guess was, that using the binary format would be more time efficient. But the follwing change (ios::binary) did not improve the computing time:

```
ofstream ofs;
ofs.open("test", ios::binary);
for(int i = 0; i < 4e7; i++){
    ofs << i;
}

ofs.close();
```

Was my guess wrong or do I need to add something?

Comment: Are you compiling with optimisation (assuming you're on Xcode change the configuration to "Release")?

Comment: I'd say what could be time more consuming in the 1st version is the value to character conversion, but the time consumption of synched I/O will clearly beat this.

Comment: @g-markulik: I removed the 'endl, still no difference.

Comment: @miguel.martin I am using Netbeans, what does it do different if I change the configuration to Release?

Comment: Try writing more than one number at a time.

Comment: @Thomas The compiler will optimize your code. And in your case, you might want to store those integers into an array and write the array directly to the stream (by casting the array to a `char*`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not really. `std::cout` is linked to the console, and the speed of this is mostly OS dependent.

That being said, there are a few simple tricks to speed up console output:

1. Create a stringstream buffer and output that in one `<<` call. This has improved the speed at which my output landed in the Windows console a lot.
2. Unsync the C++ streams from the C io library by using [`sync_with_stdio`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio).
3. If you don't need the output to be readable, you can write raw bytes and do away with any formatting of numbers, but this is a very specific case.

Comment: +1 because of your point "1.". yes the number of times output is done is the most significant factor in most implementations.

Comment: *`std::cout` is linked to the console* This is true but I can't see where in OP's code they're actually using `cout`.

Answer (score 1):

`ios::binary` only enables or disables some OS-specific conversions from text to a binary representation and back. For example, Windows represents `'\n'` as a pair of bytes (13, 10) whereas in UNIX it is represented as a single byte (10). In your case, `ios::binary` makes no difference at all.

What you could to to improve performance is to use some low-level representation for you data, so that you don't have to convert integers or doubles into text representation and back. Storing plain data in arrays and writing them into files by large chunks would be the fastest way.